# Anchor link not working while browse different page in squarespace 7.1

Tags: navigation, anchor, squarespace

I am designing a website in squarespace version 7.1, I have created anchor link using id attribute it's working fine in the [home page](https://orca-brass-lkcc.squarespace.com) but when I browse [different page](https://orca-brass-lkcc.squarespace.com/shop) then anchor link not working.

https://orca-brass-lkcc.squarespace.com/ -- anchor link working fine 
https://orca-brass-lkcc.squarespace.com/shop -- anchor link not working

use password = 1234

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks 
Asif

Comment: Hi Asif. I'm going to assume that you are referring to the links in the navigation of the site. Could you state exactly what you want to happen when a user clicks on each link. For example, I assume that "Home" should take you to the top of the home page, that "Shop" should take you to the top of the shop *page*, and "Contact" should take you to the contact *section* of the home page. Is that correct? If I do not have the correct, please state what your desired outcome is for each link in the navigation.

Comment: yes you correct but problem is when browse different page then link not working. check this page https://orca-brass-lkcc.squarespace.com/shop link not working here.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the following from your navigation:

- "Home" goes to the top of the home **page**
- "Shop" goes to the top of the shop **page**
- "Contact" goes to the contact **section** of the home page

Do the following:

- Set the "Home" link address in your navigation to "`/`" (that is, a single forward-slash)
- Set the "Shop" link address to "`/shop`"
- Set the "Contact" link address to "`/#contact`"